# When checking the assumptions for an ANOVA my tables appear very close together so they are unreadable, how do I change this?

Tags: r, anova

When checking the assumptions for an ANOVA my tables appear very close together so they are unreadable, how do I change this? Below is the code I have currently

```
library(performance)
install.packages("patchwork")
library(patchwork)
plot(check_normality(full_model))
check_model(full_model)
```

I do not remember the code to expand my tables, and google isn't being very helpful

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53rdy.png)

Comment: Have you tried just making your graphics device larger? How exactly are you viewing the results? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's not clear what you are currently seeing.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the problem as well as reproducible data as MrFlick suggested?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of what I currently can see - thank you!